# Inferring Limit from Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, proof-explanation

There are two cases where I failed to understand how limit is obtained from an inequality due to my incomplete knowledge of real analysis (limit, integration), i know basic definitions but I can't put it together under the context. I am giving the cases below-

**Case A:** $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)/x=1$ can be derived from -

$$1/\lambda<f(x)/x<\lambda \cdots (1)$$
the statement is taken from below proof-

> **Lemma 16.8.**  *Let $f:\Bbb R_{\geq1} \to \Bbb R$ be a nondecreasing function.  If the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{f(t)-t}{t^2} dt$ converges then $f(x)\sim x$.*
>
> *Proof*.  Let $F(x):=\int_1^{x}\frac{f(t)-t}{t^2}dt$.  The hypothesis is that $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)$ exists.  This implies that for all $\lambda>1$ and all $\epsilon>0$ we have $|F(\lambda x)-F(x)|<\epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $x$.
>
> Fix $\lambda>1$ and suppose there is an unbounded sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_n)\geq \lambda x_n$ for all $n\geq 1$.  For each $x_n$ we have
> $$F(\lambda x_n)-F(x_n)=\int_{x_n}^{\lambda x_n} \frac{f(t)-t}{t^2} dt\geq\int_{x_n}^{\lambda x_n}\frac{\lambda x_n-t}{t^2}dt=\int_1^{\lambda}\frac{\lambda-t}{t^2}dt=c$$ for some $c>0$, where we used the fact that $f$ is non-decreasing to get the middle inequality.  Taking $\epsilon<c$, we have $|F(\lambda x_n)-F(x_n)|=c>\epsilon$ for arbitrarily large $x_n$, a contradiction.  Thus $f(x)<\lambda x$ for all sufficiently large $x$.  A similar argument shows that $f(x)>\frac1{\lambda}x$ for all sufficiently large $x$.  These inequalities hold for all $\lambda>1$, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/x=1$.  Equivalently, $f(x)\sim x. \quad\square$

***Question:*** How $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)/x=1$ can be derived from $1/\lambda<f(x)/x<\lambda$?
I have taken it granted that $1/\lambda<f(x)/x<\lambda$. This I posted it before but could not understand the answer that was given by a forum member.

**Case B:** Also. I have been told in another post that -

> since $\frac{\log x}{x^\epsilon}\to 0$ for any $\epsilon >0$, we can
> make $\frac{\theta(x)}x$ arbitraly close to $\frac{\pi(x)\log x}{x}$.

The statement is given for below inequality -

$$\frac{1}{1-\epsilon} \frac{\theta(x)}{x}\leq \pi(x)\log(x)/x \leq \frac{\theta(x)}{x} \cdots (2)$$

The source of the inequality is given below -

> **Theorem 16.6** (Chebyshev).  *$\pi(x)\sim \frac{x}{\log x}$ if and only if $\vartheta(x)\sim x$*.
>
> *Proof*.  We clearly have $0\leq\vartheta (x)\leq\pi(x)\log x$, thus
> $$\frac{\vartheta(x)}{x}\leq\frac{\pi(x)\log x}{x}.$$
> For every $\epsilon>0$ we have
> \begin{align}
> \vartheta(x)\geq\sum_{x^{1-\epsilon}<p\leq x}\log p &\geq (1-\epsilon)(\log x)\big(\pi(x)-\pi(x^{1-\epsilon})\big)\\
> &\geq (1-\epsilon)(\log x)(\pi(x)-x^{1-\epsilon})\\
> \end{align}
> and therefore
> $$\pi(x)\leq\bigg(\frac1{1-\epsilon}\bigg)\frac{\vartheta(x)}{\log x}+x^{1-\epsilon}.$$
> Thus for all $\epsilon>0$ we have
> $$\frac{\vartheta(x)}{x}\leq\frac{\pi(x)\log x}{x}\leq \bigg(\frac1{1-\epsilon}\bigg)\frac{\vartheta(x)}{x}+\frac{\log x}{x^\epsilon}.$$
> The second term on the RHS tends to $0$ as $x\to\infty$, and the lemma follows:  by choosing $\epsilon$ sufficiently small we can make the ratios of $\vartheta(x)$ to $x$ and $\pi(x)$ to $x/\log x$ arbitrarily close together as $x\to\infty$, so if one of them tends to $1$, then so must the other.  $\quad\square$

***Question:***  If we choose $x=e^y$, then $\frac{1}{1-\epsilon} \frac{\theta(x)}{x}$ becomes negative, then the gap between $\frac{1}{1-\epsilon} \frac{\theta(x)}{x}$ and $\frac{\theta(x)}{x}$ is large, then how $\pi(x)\log(x)/x$ becomes close to $\frac{\theta(x)}{x}$?

***General Question:*** In both cases. the limit was established from inequality, but couldn't comprehend how it is done, could anyone please elaborate it how is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard technique used in analysis and it is just one step away from the definition of limit. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exist a $\lambda>1$ such that $$1-\epsilon<\frac{1}{\lambda}<\lambda<1+\epsilon $$ Note that inequality in middle $1 /\lambda <\lambda $ is obvious if $\lambda >1$. Also the first inequality holds if $\epsilon\geq 1$ and we can take $\lambda<2$ so that the last inequality also holds.

When $\epsilon<1$ then we just need to choose $\lambda <\min(1+\epsilon,1/(1-\epsilon))$ and with this choice the desired inequality holds.

Now you can proceed like this. Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Then from the argument given above we know that there is a $\lambda >1$ such that we have $1-\epsilon<1/\lambda <\lambda <1+\epsilon$. It is known that $1/\lambda <f(x) /x<\lambda $ for all sufficiently large $x$. Combining these inequalities we get $$1-\epsilon<\frac{1}{\lambda} <\frac{f(x)} {x} <\lambda <1+\epsilon $$ for all sufficiently large $x$. By definition of limit we now have $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) / x=1$.

---

The second question uses a fairly standard technique based on $\limsup, \liminf $. The idea is that if $f(x) \leq g(x) $ then this inequality (only the weak version $\leq$) is preserved by applying $\limsup, \liminf$.

You can apply $\limsup, \liminf$ to the last equation dealing with $\vartheta(x), \pi(x) $ and then get the desired result. Thus for example lets apply $\limsup$ to get $$\limsup_{x\to\infty} \frac{\vartheta(x)} {x} \leq \limsup _{x\to \infty} \frac{\pi(x) \log x} {x} \leq \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}\limsup_{x\to\infty} \frac{\vartheta(x)} {x}, 0<\epsilon <1$$ From this (along with corresponding $\liminf$ inequality) we can see that if one of the ratios $\vartheta(x) /x, (\pi(x) \log x) /x$ has a limit the other one also has the same limit.

---

The definition of a limit involves inequalities and thus it is natural to expect that they can be evaluated using inequalities. It is the theorems for evaluating limits which give us the impression that limits can be evaluated using some sort of algebra. But deep down its all inequalities of a very specific kind.

Comment: for the case B,  If $ 0<\epsilon <1$ then I have no question, I understand how the term converges, but how we know $ 0<\epsilon <1$ ? in the proof it is written $ 0<\epsilon$.

Comment: Plz review this answer and comment if it is correct or not : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3410520/613063

Comment: @Andrew: that's wrong. Author's argument works only for $0<\epsilon <1$ and it is sufficient to consider only these values of $\epsilon $.

Comment: What is wrong? my comment or the answer I requested u to review?

Comment: The argument in your question works only for $0<\epsilon <1$ and not for $\epsilon >0$ so this should be fixed. Regarding your answe, it is needlessly complicated and further it only shows that there is a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) /x_n\to 1$. It does not show that $f(x) /x\to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

I just will answer your first question. Please, write just one question per post.

From the first quote of your post we knows that for each chosen $\lambda>1$ there is some $y_\lambda>1$ such that $f(x)/x<\lambda$ for all $x>y_\lambda$ and some $z_\lambda >1$ such that $f(x)/x>1/\lambda$ for all $x>z_\lambda$, thus setting $w_\lambda :=\max\{y_\lambda ,z_\lambda \}$ we find that
$$
\forall \lambda >1,\exists w_\lambda >1,\forall x>w_\lambda : \frac1\lambda<\frac{f(x)}x<\lambda\tag1
$$
Then from $\rm (1)$ taking limits we can see that
$$
\forall \lambda >1:\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\leqslant \lambda
\\
\qquad \implies\limsup_{x\to \infty }\frac{f(x)}x\leqslant \inf\{\lambda:\lambda >1\} =1\tag2
$$
and similarly
$$
\forall \lambda >1:\liminf_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\geqslant \frac1\lambda
\\
\qquad \implies\liminf_{x\to \infty }\frac{f(x)}x\geqslant \sup\{\tfrac1\lambda:\lambda >1\} =1\tag3
$$
And because $\liminf_{x\to\infty}g(x)\leqslant \limsup_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ for any real-valued function $g$ then 
$$
\limsup_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}x=\liminf_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}x=1\\
\implies \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}x=1
$$
$\Box$

Comment: How could u say $x_n$ large enough such that for $\lambda _n:=\tfrac{n+1}{n}$ ?

Comment: it is stated in the body of the first quote, that is "Thus $f(x)<\lambda x$ for all sufficiently large $x$", what means that for any chosen $\lambda>1$ is some $y>1$ such that $\lambda>f(x)/x$ for all $x>y$. Then I set a value for $\lambda$ and call it $\lambda_n$ and I proceed. I would rewrite the answer to make it more clear

Comment: **Let $(\lambda_n)$ any decreasing sequence that converge to $1$.** ...this is the key thing i am not getting it , you assumed it, what if $(\lambda_n)$ doesn't  converge to $1$? what ensures that $(\lambda_n)$ converge to $1$ always ?

Comment: we can choose any such sequence because the inequalities holds for any chosen $\lambda >1$, the point is that we choose it to show that necessarily the limit must be one. I changed a bit the argument (again) to something slightly simpler

Comment: Plz review this answer and comment if it is correct or not : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3410520/613063

Comment: Your comment and initial answer is more clear than the updated answer. Upvoted.

Comment: @Andrew if you like it is fine, but I think that the updated answer is simpler because we dont need to choose any sequence or work with sequences at all: the idea above is that if $a$ is a real number (some limit in $\Bbb R$ is a number, provided that such limit exists) such that $a<b$ for all elements of some set $A$ in $\Bbb R $ then $a\leqslant \inf A$, what is a basic theorem of real analysis (a similar thing can be shown for the supremum)